# button in PSD as multiple layers into mobile code java

Tags: java, android, ios, user-interface, photoshop

A PSD file i'm working with has its icons designed IN PSD using layers that are a result of using magic wand, rectangle tool, circle tools etc.

For example, an icon can be made up of 4 different layers in 1 photoshop folder (ie using magic wand 2x, rectangle tool 1x, circle tool 1x)

I understand that if an icon in PSD were to be usable in code it should be in jpeg, png format, please correct me if I'm wrong as I'm new to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are absolutely correct to be usable it should be either png or jpeg(there are others too). Png and 9 patch png are preferred in android. You can find more about it on the [developers website.](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html)

Comment: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/5419/exporting-groups-of-layers-from-a-psd-to-a-single-png-file-using-photoshop?rq=1 does this solve my problem?

Comment: I am not a designer but a developer so I cannot say for sure about you link but reading it sounded like a solution but dont take my word for it